# Mapping [-1,+1] floats to Q31 fixed-point

Tags: c, signal-processing, fixed-point

I need to convert float to Q31 fixed-point, Q31 meaning 1 sign bit, 0 bits for integer part, and 31 bits for fractional part. This means that Q31 can only represent numbers in the range `[-1,0.9999]`.

By definition, when converting from float to fixed-point, a multiplication by `2ˇN` is done, where N is the fractional part size, in this case 31.

However, I got confused with this code, it doesn't look right, but works:

```
#define q31_float_to_int(x) ( (int) ( (float)(x)*(float)0x7FFFFFFF ) )
```

And it seems to work OK. For example:

```
int a = q31_float_to_int(0.5f);
```

gives `Hex: 0x40000000`, which is OK.

Why is the multipication here done with `2ˇ31 - 1`, and not just `2ˇ31`?

Comment: `(float)0x7FFFFFFF` is `2147483648.00000`: http://ideone.com/mawlXx . Even after casting to `unsigned` the value holds: http://ideone.com/7WMeRE

Comment: Hmm?? How come 0x7FFFFFFF ends up as 2147483648 and not 2147483647??

Comment: Because 2147483647 is not representable as a `float` and so the nearest representable number will be taken, which is 2147483648.

Comment: Any idea why didn't the above code just use `(float)0x8000000` instead of `(float)0x7FFFFFFF`?

Comment: Perhaps the author was trying to avoid overflow and/or wished to express the value `1.0` on architectures where `INT_MAX` is `0x7FFFFFFF`. Unfortunately, this solution is unlikely to be successful *or* correct.

Comment: Would it help to make `float` a `double`, `(double)(x)*(double)0x7FFFFFFFULL)`? This would require casting input `x` from `float` to `double` every time.

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/q/71361635/7224685

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above is not a good solution to convert from float to fixed point. I am guessing whoever wrote the code used the scale factor of `0x7FFFFFFF` to avoid an overflow when the input is `1.0`. The correct scaling factor is `2^31` and not `2^31 - 1`. Note that there are also precision issues when converting a `float` (with 24 bits of precision) to an `Q1.31` (with 31 bits of precision). Consider saturating the input data before multiplication:

```
const float Q31_MAX_F =  0x0.FFFFFFp0F;
const float Q31_MIN_F = -1.0F;
float clamped = fmaxf(fminf(input, Q31_MAX_F), Q31_MIN_F);
```

The code above will clamp `input` to the range of `[-1.0, 1.0)`. The constant`Q31_MAX_F` is approximately `1 - (2 ^ -24)`, considering 24-bits of precision, and `Q31_MIN_F` is `-1`. Then you can multiply `clamped` by `2^31`, or even better, use [scalbnf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/scalbn), or [ldexpf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ldexp):

```
int result = (int) scalbnf(clamped, 31);
```

And if you want rounding:

```
int result = (int) roundf(scalbnf(clamped, 31)));
```

Comment: Why use `0x7FFFFF00.p-31F;` rather than the largest `float` under 1?  `(0x7FFFFF80.p-31F;)`  Better yet, be portable: `Q31_MAX_F =  nextafterf(1.0,0.0); Q31_MIN_F = -1.0f;`

Comment: To _round_, suggest  `int32_t result = (int32_t) lround(scalbnf(clamped, 31));`

Comment: Thanks. Updated according to your comments.

Comment: Detail: "constant `Q31_MAX_F` is 1 - (2 ^ -24)".  Typical `float` has 24-bits of precision.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Typical [IEEE754 single precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) has 23 mantissa bits, with an implied MSB, which gives 24 bits of precision.

Comment: Also 2^31 is `clamped<<31`. But what is p in hex representation of float how can I know more about it?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to use STM32's CORDIC for hardware-accelerated trigonometry, and left unsatisfied with the accepted answer (and everything else I found on the web), I came up with a simpler (but slightly less precise) algorithm for Q31/F32 conversion:

```
#define Q31_SCALAR (float)M_PI
#define F32_TO_Q31(F) (int32_t)((fmodf((F)+Q31_SCALAR,2.f*Q31_SCALAR) + ((F)<-Q31_SCALAR?Q31_SCALAR:-Q31_SCALAR)) * ((float)(INT32_MAX+1u)/Q31_SCALAR))
#define Q31_TO_F32(Q) ((int32_t)(Q) / (float)(INT32_MAX+1u))
#define CORDIC_COS_SIN(RAD,COS_VAR,SIN_VAR) { hcordic.Instance->WDATA = F32_TO_Q31(RAD); \
  (COS_VAR) = Q31_TO_F32(hcordic.Instance->RDATA); (SIN_VAR) = Q31_TO_F32(hcordic.Instance->RDATA); }
```

This will map floats from [-π, +π] to approximately [`INT32_MIN`, `INT32_MAX`[. If the input value is out of range, it will be "wrapped" back into that range (e.g. -5.9π will be treated as 0.1π).

If instead you want to map [-1, +1] as per the original question, simply use the following:

```
#define Q31_SCALAR 1.f
```

Comment: `M_PI` is usually a `double` constant, so `(F)/Q31_SCALAR` is a `double` quotient followed by a `double` sum and then conversion to a `float` for the `fmodf()` call.  If you want `float` math, suggest `#define 0x1.921fb54442d1846ap+1f`

Comment: "This will map floats from [-π, +π] to [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX]" --> I did not see that when running code.  Values near `M_PI` became `INT_MIN`.  What was the result of your edge case tests?

Comment: Once done with `float` operations, this codes unnecessary loses precision with `(F)/Q31_SCALAR+1` when `F` is a small magnitude value.  Also note loss of precision with `(float)INT32_MAX` lopping off 8 least significant digits.  Overall code has quality conversion issues.

Comment: I think the goal should shift from "[-π, +π] to [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX]" to "[-π, +π) to [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX + 1LL)"

Comment: The precision losses and weird edge cases are all intended. My objective was to trim off cycles while still reaching a reasonably correct result.

Comment: OK, Yet I suspect a good precision and fast enough is possible along the lines of `((int) (fmodf((F), (float)M_PI)*((INT_MAX+1LL)/ (float) M_PI))))` or `lround()` vs. cast..  Good luck.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I settled on the last edit from my answer. I need the `2.f` and ternary to ensure the input is properly wrapped from -π to +π for every 2π interval.